# Return subform values based on muliple criteria in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to select one or more values from the same field in subform 1 and display the applicable values in subform 2.

I have done this kind of thing by selecting criteria from multiple fields but not with multiple line-item values from the same field. My first thought was to build a dynamic SQL string to populate subform 2 but just wondering if there is an easier way to do this.

[image]

At the moment if I select a line-item in subform 1 (flight itinerary), subform 2 will only show the applicable flight segments for that itinerary. If a customer has more that one flight itinerary for the same trip in subform 1 I need to show all flight segments for the entire trip in subform 2.

Comment: Conventional approach is selecting items from a multi-select listbox and VBA builds comma separated parameter array for use with IN() function, result something like: `ItineraryID IN(4,7,9,11)`. It is possible to loop through records selected on form but records can only be continuously selected on form, i.e. they have to be next to each other.

Comment: My understanding of a multi-select listbox is you can select one of more items in the listbox to filter something else but you can't actually store the multi-select values. Plus I don't want to have to physically select anything. Subform 2 should always filter based on whatever is stored in Subform 1. If I was to do this with VBA my thinking was to loop through the values in the first subform and build an SQL string to populate the second subform. Just thought I would pose the question here in case there was an easier way to do this.

Comment: I liked the concept of usiing the IN() operator. I discovered IN() will actually accept input from a subquery. So I have the subquery retrieve the same value(s) that exist in the first subform and this seems to provide the desired results in the second subform. When I select a different customer and criteria changes, the second subform seems to update automatically without me having to trigger a requery which is cool. I will continue to test but it seems to be working so far.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Lee Mac's suggestion to utilize the IN() function/operator, I was able to feed the IN() function with a subquery string to return the data I need without having to loop through a recordset. Just had to ensure that the subquery only returned values for a single field (in this case the ID field) or it would error out.

I created a function to fill in the Segment numbers in order.